# Edit and read binary files?

Tags: performance, binary, compression

For a data compression project, I want to be able to edit and read binary files, For this particular project it is very important to get 256 combinations out of 1 byte, I noticed saving one character in notepad resulted in a 1 byte file, this is great, so long as there are 256 characters linked to all 8-bit combinations. ASCII currently offers about 218 typeable characters, the rest are control characters

I know that there are 256 combinations in 8 bits (1 byte) because of 2 ^ 8 = 256 and i want to be able to use all those combinations for data compression. So a binary editor and reader would be perfect!

Comment: Not clear at all. What does character representation have to do with binary values?

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: Your question is valid but you have some incorrect information. ASCII is a character set of 128 characters, with one encoding, which emits byte values from 0 to 127. Text files generally haven't been ASCII in several decades. Your 218 number must be based on some other character set, maybe ISO 8859-1. But that's not relevant to text files, in general, being examples of files with a relatively low information to storage ratio. You might find that an algorithm based on the actual byte values used in a file (or block) will give better compression than one that considers only a fixed, larger set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're question is not specific enough. What kind of tooling are you looking for? 
Hex is not fake binary, it's just another representation of the same data.

If you're on windows, open up the calculator and switch it to 'programming mode'. It'll allow you to convert values from decimal, hexadecimal and binary representation.
Then find yourself an hex-editor and you're in business.

Since you mention 'ASCII', I suggest you read Joel Spolskys post on character encodings. It's an excellent post, which clarifies how difficult it can be to show plain text. The post is from 2003, but still valid.
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/